# How to upload a file to Nexus repository manager with curl?

Tags: curl, nexus, snapshot

I am trying to upload a file to a snapshot repository on a Nexus 2.14.11-01 server with the following command:

```
curl -v -u username:password --upload-file file.ext \
    https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ \
    com.example.snapshot/com/example/myscripts/1.2.3/file-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.ext
```

which should work according to this [support page](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2-). In my case it fails with the following output:

```
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Connected to example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.example.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: -
*    start date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> PUT /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com.example.snapshot/com/example/myscripts/1.2.3/file-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.ext HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Authorization: Basic dHyZXcabzpAbmVlMjVa
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7837
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 09:06:14 GMT
< Server: Nexus/2.14.11-01
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Length: 0
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you're getting a 403 (forbidden), which indicates that your login credentials were accepted, but the user doing the upload does not have permissions to upload into the repository.

Second, the file is not in valid Maven repository layout.  It needs to be in this form:

> /$groupIdWithSlashes/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version.$extension
>   /$groupIdWithSlashes/$artifactId/$version/$artifactId-$version-$classifier.$extension

```
https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ \
    com.example.snapshot/com/example/myscripts/file/ \
    1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/file-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.ext
```

Third, you really should be using maven to do the upload, so a pom file will be generated.  Artifacts in maven repositories should always have associate pom files.  Using the "deploy:deploy-file" maven goal will generate a pom:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-2-#maven-deploy-file

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out if my user has upload rights for the snapshot repository or if it is even configured to accept any files via HTTP PUT?

Comment: @JJD You can learn more about NXRM2 security here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Managing+Security.  You'll have to check what roles you have and what privileges those roles have.  If you're not an admin, you'll have to ask someone who can access those pages.  All hosted repos should be able to accept PUT afaik.  Groups and proxies can't.

Comment: @joedragons I checked the roles and privileges together with the admin but we could not figure out, why the upload is denied via _curl_. I also tested the path which rseddon explained in her answer - w/o success. - One thing I did not mention before is that the tab to manually upload files does *not* show up in the snapshot repository but does show up in a similar release repository.

Comment: @JJD I can tell you that no Upload UI for snapshots is not you, that's how NXRM2 is designed.  You could check if everything works for a full admin, if so, then you know what you need to figure out first.  I cannot give you specifics via comment, but could try CRUD (create read update delete) for the repo type and scale down if that works.

Comment: @joedragons Is the Upload UI for snapshots visible for any user such as full admins?

Comment: @JJD no that's what I was trying to say=)

Answer (score 3):

The only catch is, to use user and password token code, NOT PLAIN TEXT Value in curl command

```
curl -v -u username_token_code:password_token_code --upload-file file.ext \
    https://example.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/ \
    com.example.snapshot/com/example/myscripts/1.2.3/file-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.ext
```

[How to generate User and Password token code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN8Au.png)