# CURL cmd throwing error when I look to transfer the jar file from server to nexus repo Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse HTTP/1.1 405 POST

Tags: nexus

Why is the CURL command throwing following error when I look to transfer the jar file from my server to nexus repository

curl -v -F r=1 -F hasPom=false -F e=jar -F g=org.sonatype.plugins -F a=nexus-staging-maven-plugin -F v=1.0 -F p=jar -F file=mozaic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -u admin:Easy123 http://192.168.12.176:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.12.176 (192.168.12.176) port 8081 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /repository/maven-snapshots/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.12.176:8081
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46RWFzeTEyMw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 860
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d5e1136698e938a7
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 405 POST
< Server: Nexus/3.41.0-01 (OSS)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Allow: GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 1738
<

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>405 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>(new Image).src="../../favicon.ico?3.41.0-01"</script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon-32x32.png?3.41.0-01" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="../../safari-pinned-tab.svg?3.41.0-01" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon-16x16.png?3.41.0-01" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico?3.41.0-01">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../../mstile-144x144.png?3.41.0-01">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00a300">



 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../static/css/nexus-content.css?3.41.0-01"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nexus-header">
  <a href="../..">
    <div class="product-logo">
      <img src="../../static/rapture/resources/icons/x32/nexus-white.png?3.41.0-01" alt="Product logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="product-id">
      <div class="product-id__line-1">
        <span class="product-name">Nexus Repository Manager</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-id__line-2">
        <span class="product-spec">OSS 3.41.0-01</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>



<div class="nexus-body">
  <div class="content-header">
    <img src="../../static/rapture/resources/icons/x32/exclamation.png?3.41.0-01" alt="Exclamation point" aria-role="presentation"/>
    <span class="title">Error 405</span>
    <span class="description">Method Not Allowed</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-body">
    <div class="content-section">
      POST
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.12.176 left intact
```

Comment: Please add the error that you get to your question!

Comment: The HTML response shows `Error 405 Method Not Allowed`, and the CURL appears to do a post which nexus doesn't like: `< HTTP/1.1 405 POST`. Try one of the following: `< Allow: GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE`. It looks like you're trying to upload a file, so i would expect that `PUT` should be used. For downloading probably `GET`.

Comment: Where should we put this condition to allow: GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE?

Comment: That is already configured; the allow header on the response tells you what the server allows. You could try to follow these guides for [Nexus 2](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-Repo-2-) or [Nexus 3](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-files-into-Nexus-3-). Or check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106640/how-to-upload-a-file-to-nexus-repository-manager-with-curl

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have followed the PUT API process, it gives error too : 

curl -v -u admin:Easy1234 --upload-file mozaic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar http://192.168.12.176:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/mozaic-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar




Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2022 03:53:20 GMT
< Server: Nexus/3.41.0-01 (OSS)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
< Connection: close

Comment: Also, one more thing I should mention is that since it is being done on test server, I have allocated only 1 core cpu to the nexus server, would that cause an issue?

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` means your username and/or password are wrong. I just verified the command on one of my nexus servers and that works fine. But do remember that the URL must be the full path where you want the artifact to land, otherwise it will be put in the root of the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following response from the Nexus server: `< HTTP/1.1 405 POST`.
And in the HTML response body we can (also) see what HTTP 405 POST means:

> Error 405 Method Not Allowed

So the `POST` method is not allowed on this URL. That is the result of trying to do a `form` upload via curl, which is not supported. The Nexus server also kindly responds with the methods it does allow: `< Allow: GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE`

If you want to upload a file into a repository, you are supposed to use a HTTP `PUT` command. You can find the documentation for how this is executed online:

- For nexus 2: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465818-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-Repo-2-
- For nexus 3: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008-How-can-I-programmatically-upload-files-into-Nexus-3-

For example a direct deploy with `curl` for nexus 2 (and also 3, the command is the same besides the specific `/repositories` path):

> You can do an HTTP PUT of a file into /content/repositories/<repo-id>/<path-of-file>.  Using curl you can do this with:
>
> ```
> curl -v -u admin:admin123 --upload-file pom.xml http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.pom
> ```

Watch out; you're supposed to manually put the correct `groupid`, `artifactid`, `version` and desired `filename` into this URL, otherwise you'll upload the file in the root of the repository! In this example that would be the last part of the URL: `org/foo/1.0/foo-1.0.pom`

An example of executing this on a Nexus server i have access to:

```
curl -v -u user:pass --upload-file some.jar http://host/nexus/content/repositories/repo/group/artifact/version/some.jar
```

With `curl` command logging (minus REDACTED private information):

```
*   Trying host...
* Connected to host (ip) port PORT (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> PUT /nexus/content/repositories/REDACTED HTTP/1.1
> Host: REDACTED
> Authorization: Basic REDACTED
> User-Agent: curl/7.83.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 18783
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2022 15:01:50 GMT
< Server: Nexus/2.10.0-02
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/nexus; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 30-Aug-2022 15:01:50 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host REDACTED left intact
```

And as we can see this uploaded the artifact: `* We are completely uploaded and fine` with result `< HTTP/1.1 201 Created`